# Maintaining the aspect ratio of the background of an imageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a matrix of `imageView` that the user can select some images.
I load the images to the view as a "BackgroundResource" for two reasons:

1. It was the easiest way for me to load the jpg files on the java class
2. When an image is selected I wanted to give the user some feedback, adding the src on the background gave me the option to add a checked sign.

The only problem is that it is harder to maintain the image ratio in the background. All my images are jpg files and I want the image in the background to be in the size **120dpX120dp** but maintain it`s aspect ratio,

What I Tried:

- Changing the `ScaleType` of the `ImageView`
- add a `RelativeLayout` surrounding the `ImageView`

this is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".LockScreenActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleText"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Select 3 images"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img1"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/img2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleText" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img2"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleText"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img3"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleText" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img5"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img2" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img6"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img3" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img7"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/img8"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img4" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img8"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img5" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img9"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img8"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img6" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img4"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/img5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="76dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="OK"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img8"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.673" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/backBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Back"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/submit"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/submit"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my java code to set the `imageBackground`- all of my Background images are in the format "img"+i -> i in range(1,numOfImages):

```
    private void updateImageView(ArrayList<String> images) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= images.size(); i++) {
        int drawableResourceId = 
        this.getResources().getIdentifier(images.get(i-1), "drawable", 
        this.getPackageName());
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier("img" +i, "id", 
        this.getPackageName());
        ImageView img = findViewById(id);
        img.setBackgroundResource(drawableResourceId);
        img.setTag(images.get(i-1));
        img.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    }
}
```

**How can I maintain the ratio in this structure?**

**is the easiest way is just to make all the images same height and width?** (adding some transparent height or width padding)

Comment: did you tried scaleType = "fitXY"

Comment: Yes, I tried all of the scaleType options

Comment: use this layout file which i modified from yours.

Answer (score 0):

use this xml layout that i modified from yours. there were some problem in your layout binding which you can relate.  so because of binding your layout problem arise. also remove the last line of code from activity. `

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleText"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Select 3 images"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_bg_shape"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/img2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleText" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="121dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bird"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/img3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleText" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img3"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow_down_minimize_orange"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleText" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img5"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow_down_minimize_orange"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/img6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img6"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow_down_minimize_orange"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img7"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow_down_minimize_orange"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/img8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img4" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img8"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow_down_minimize_orange"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/img9"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img5" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img9"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow_down_minimize_orange"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img6" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img4"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow_down_minimize_orange"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/img5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="OK"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.673" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Back"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/submit"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/submit"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`

Comment: I really appreciate that but still, the images are distorted.
I don't want to crop any part of the image, but I prefer to have a part of the view transparent While keeping its 120dp size,  then cropping the image or changing its aspect ratio